# Adapt GUI to screen size in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

[image]

I have a game developed in Java, with Swing and AWT libraries. As the game is in full screen I would like to adapt it to many screens as possible. I tested it on my PC, which screen size is 1680 x 1050, but in my laptop, which is 1440 x 900, seems to be a bit wrong with the dimensions.

My question is, is there any formula (for screen width and height), to make the Score (+ the number), Quit (that Q which hides at the bottom-right), Shots (+ the number) and Menu perfectly situated, at each corner of the screen? Also the dice seems not to be centered right.

Comment: You could draw it to an image, and then redraw the image with scaling, or you could use offsets (Menu is x from the left and y from the *bottom*, quit is x from the *right* and y from the *bottom*, etc.) based on corners that you will get from, as MadProgrammer said, getWidth() and getHeight().

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on "magic" numbers. Query the component for its width and height by using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` values

Depending on your needs, you might even be able to scale portions of the screen

Comment: +1 *you might even be **Abel** to*: i first thought you are mentioning him to be one of the toon character :)

Comment: And I thought that he was talking about mathematical commutative groups, as opposed to non-Abelian Lie groups... 1+

Comment: @Sage 1 iPad, 1 squirming 18 month on lap and 1 piece of toast, not make for a quality typing experience ;)